# How can I find the value of $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} A \cdot \frac{1 - e^{-Bn}}{(Cn + D)^3} $ in terms of the constants $ A $, $ B $, $ C $ and $ D $?

Tags: limits, summation, infinity

I really don't know how to approach this. I plotted the sum on a graphing calculator and it definitely does converge - I would like to see how the limit depends on the constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} A  \frac{1 - e^{-Bn}}{(Cn + D)^3}=A\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1  }{(Cn + D)^3}-A\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-Bn}}{(Cn + D)^3}$$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1  }{(Cn + D)^3}=-\frac{1}{2 C^3}\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{C+D}{C}\right)$$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-Bn}}{(Cn + D)^3}=\frac{e^{-B}}{C^3}\,\,\Phi \left(e^{-B},3,\frac{C+D}{C}\right)$$

So you have your result in terms of the polygamma function and the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.

Comment: Thank you very much!